# Meaning of image in intel pin tool

Tags: intel-pin

I am new on Intel pin tool, and begin to study pin tool recently. In tutorial, it describe modes of pin tool:

> Sometimes, however, it can be useful to look at different granularity
>   than a trace. For this purpose Pin offers two additional modes: image
>   and routine instrumentation. These modes are implemented by "caching"
>   instrumentation requests and hence incur a space overhead, these modes
>   are also referred to as ahead-of-time instrumentation.

I want to know what is the meaning of "image".

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can have more details about images in the documentation of the "IMG" Object: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/group__IMG__BASIC__API.html

> An IMG represents all the data structures corresponding to a binary (executable). Can be accessed at instrumentation time and analysis time. Note: Shared libraries are also represented by the IMG abstraction. Moreover, the IMG objects are created in a lazy fashion. Only if a shared library is loaded and IMG is created. Over the lifetime of a process the number IMG objects created may hence increase.
>   APIs from this group are available in any thread, including any internal thread spawned by the tool.

You can see that an image represents a binary (executable)... which contains sections (.text for instance)... which contains routines... etc

Comment: Note that binaries/executables also include shared objects/DLLs.

Comment: Thank you. I think that explains well.